# Mocking context for react tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-context

So I have this context:

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';
import { AuthState } from '../types/auth-state.type';

const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  profile: null,
  socket: null,
};

export interface IAuthContext {
  authState: AuthState;
  setAuthState: React.Dispatch<AuthState>;
}

export const AuthContext = createContext<IAuthContext>({
  authState: initialState,
  setAuthState: () => {},
});

function AuthContextProvider(props: any) {
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState<AuthState>(initialState);
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={{ authState, setAuthState }}>{props.children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}
export default AuthContextProvider;
```

along with this component:

```
export const SelectedClientWrapper = ({ children }: ISelectedClientWrapper) => {
  const { authState, setAuthState } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { clientsState } = useContext(ClientsContext);
  const [cachedClientId, setCachedClientId] = useState<string>('');

  useMountEffect(() => {
    getCachedSelectedClient().then((r) => {
      setCachedClientId(r);
    });
  });

  console.log('profile', authState.profile);
  if (!authState.profile) {
    console.log(2);
    const selectedClient = clientsState.clients.find((client) => client.client_id === cachedClientId);
    console.log({ selectedClient });
    if (selectedClient) {
      console.log(3);
      setAuthState({ ...authState, profile: selectedClient });
      setCachedClientId('');
    }
  }
  return children;
};
```

And here are my tests:

```
export const authenticatedInitial = {
  authState: {
    isAuthenticated: true,
    profile: null,
    socket: null,
  },
  setAuthState: () => {},
};
export const clientsMultipleClientsInitial = {
  clientsState: {
    isFetching: false,
    clients: mockClientsProfiles,
    profileToGreet: mockClientsProfiles[0],
    hasMultipleClients: true,
  },
  setClientsState: () => {},
};
export const MockAuthContext = ({ initialValue, children }: IMockAuthContext) => {
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={initialValue}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

const renderComponent = (
  { initialAuthValue = authenticatedInitial, initialClientsValue = clientsMultipleClientsInitial }: IRenderComponent = {
    initialAuthValue: authenticatedInitial,
    initialClientsValue: clientsMultipleClientsInitial,
  }
): RenderResult =>
  render(
    <MockAuthContext initialValue={initialAuthValue}>
      <MockClientsContext initialValue={initialClientsValue}>
        <MockRouterWrapper>
          <SelectedClientWrapper>
            <I18nextWrapper>
              <Route path={RoutesEnum.clients}>
                <div>clients</div>
              </Route>
              <Route path={RoutesEnum.stake}>
                <div>stake</div>
              </Route>
            </I18nextWrapper>
          </SelectedClientWrapper>
        </MockRouterWrapper>
      </MockClientsContext>
    </MockAuthContext>
  );
```

So it all looks good and makes sense.

The logic of the component is:

if auth.profile is not set find the client that might be cached. If he is cached, set it as profile, and clear the state (this prevents the site from being stuck on one client, async and all that). Otherwise just return children.

It works when I test it manually. The problem is, when I try to mock it, it doesn't update the context, so it does all the magic, it finds the user, runs the code in the last if, but the context is not updated, so it redirects to the wrong route. So in logs I get:

```
  console.log
    profile null

      at SelectedClientWrapper (src/components/SelectedClientWrapper/SelectedClientWrapper.tsx:21:11)

  console.log
    2

      at SelectedClientWrapper (src/components/SelectedClientWrapper/SelectedClientWrapper.tsx:23:13)

  console.log
    { selectedClient: undefined }

      at SelectedClientWrapper (src/components/SelectedClientWrapper/SelectedClientWrapper.tsx:25:13)

  console.log
    profile null

      at SelectedClientWrapper (src/components/SelectedClientWrapper/SelectedClientWrapper.tsx:21:11)

  console.log
    2

      at SelectedClientWrapper (src/components/SelectedClientWrapper/SelectedClientWrapper.tsx:23:13)

  console.log
    {
      selectedClient: {
        ...... values
      }
    }

      at SelectedClientWrapper (src/components/SelectedClientWrapper/SelectedClientWrapper.tsx:25:13)

  console.log
    3

      at SelectedClientWrapper (src/components/SelectedClientWrapper/SelectedClientWrapper.tsx:27:15)

  console.log
    profile null

      at SelectedClientWrapper (src/components/SelectedClientWrapper/SelectedClientWrapper.tsx:21:11)

  console.log
    2

      at SelectedClientWrapper (src/components/SelectedClientWrapper/SelectedClientWrapper.tsx:23:13)

  console.log
    { selectedClient: undefined }

      at SelectedClientWrapper (src/components/SelectedClientWrapper/SelectedClientWrapper.tsx:25:13)

  console.log
    <body>
      <div>
        <div>
          clients
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Why is it not updating the context? What am I missing?

Comment: It might be caused by how you're rendering your test. Are you using React testRender, Enzyme, React Testing Library, or something else?

Comment: As tagged, react-testing-library + jest